# Is there a struct function for finding the longest and not-repeating length substring within a string?

Tags: c++

The aim of the function is to find out the longest and not repeating substring, so I need to find out the start position of the substring and the length of it. The thing I'm struggling with is the big O notation should be O(n). Therefore I cannot use nested for loops to check whether each letter is repeated.
I created a struct function like this but I don't know how to continue:

```
struct Answer {             
    int start;              
    int length;
};
```

```
Answer findsubstring(char *string){
    Answer sub={0, 0}

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        
    }
    return (sub)
}
```

For example, the input is `HelloWorld`, and the output should be `World`.The length is 5.
If the input is`abagkfleoKi`, then the output is `bagkfleoKi`. The length is 10.
Also, if the length of two strings is the same, pick the latter one.

Comment: Isn't `"HelloW"` containing a repetition of `'l'`s?

Comment: Oh sorry, the output of HelloWorld should be 'orld'

Comment: Why not `World`?

Comment: Mistyped. You're right.

Comment: Why is the output in the second case not `bagkfleoKi`?

Comment: Yes the output is `bagkfleoKi`

Comment: I have edited the output because it has too many mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::unordered_map<char, size_t>` to store the indices past the last occurance of a certain char.

Keep the currently best match as well as the match you currently test. Iterating through the chars of the input result in 2 cases you need to handle:

1. the char already occured and the last occurance of the char requires you to move the start of the potential match to avoid the char from occuring twice: Update the answer with the match ending just before the current char, if that's better than the current answer.
2. Otherwise: Just update the map

```
void printsubstring(const char* input)
{
    std::unordered_map<char, size_t> lastOccurances;

    Answer answer{ 0, 0 };

    size_t currentPos = 0;
    size_t currentStringStart = 0;

    char c;

    while ((c = input[currentPos]) != 0)
    {
        auto entry = lastOccurances.insert({ c, currentPos + 1 });

        if (!entry.second)
        {
            if (currentStringStart < entry.first->second && currentPos - currentStringStart > answer.length)
            {
                // need to move the start of the potential answer
                // -> check, if the match up to the char before the current char was better
                answer.start = currentStringStart;
                answer.length = currentPos - currentStringStart;
                currentStringStart = entry.first->second;
            }
            
            entry.first->second = currentPos + 1;
        }
        ++currentPos;
    }

    // check the match ending at the end of the string
    if (currentPos - currentStringStart > answer.length)
    {
        answer.start = currentStringStart;
        answer.length = currentPos - currentStringStart;
    }

    std::cout << answer.start << ", " << answer.length << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::string_view(input + answer.start, answer.length) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll outline one possible solution.

1. You'll need two loops. One for pointing at the start of the substring and one that points at the end.

   ```
   auto stringlen = std::strlen(string);
   for(size_t beg = 0; beg < stringlen - sub.length; ++beg) {
       // See point 2.
       for(size_t end = beg; end < stringlen; ++end) {
           // See point 3.
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a "blacklist" of characters already seen in the substring.

   ```
   bool blacklist[1 << CHAR_BIT]{}; // zero initialized
   ```
3. Check if the current `end` character is already in the `blacklist` and `break` out of the loop if it is, otherwise, put it in the blacklist.

   ```
   if(blacklist[ static_cast<unsigned char>(string[end]) ]) break;
   else {
       blacklist[ static_cast<unsigned char>(string[end]) ] = true;
       // See point 4.
   }
   ```
4. Check if the length of the current substring (`end - beg + 1`) is greater than the longest you currently have (`sub.length`). If it is longer, store `sub.start = beg` and `sub.length = end - beg + 1`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9a9x7z) and [Demo using a `bitset<>` instead](https://godbolt.org/z/KbPodv)