# I'm getting an error for my c++ code when my input string contains spaces

Tags: c++, string, stl

Problem Link :https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) 
    {
     
     if(s.length()==0)
         return 0;
        
     if(s.length()==1)
         return 1;
     
     int ans=0;
     int len=0;
     //s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
     vector<int> count(257,0);
     vector<int> last_index(257,0);
        
     for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
     {
         if(count[s[i]-'0']==0)
         {  
            count[s[i]-'0']++;
            last_index[s[i]-'0']=i; //storing the index of the character
            len++;
            ans=max(ans,len);
         }
         else if(count[s[i]-'0']>=1)
         {
             fill(count.begin(), count.begin()+last_index[s[i]-'0'], 0); // reducing the count to 0 till the last position of the matched character
             len=i-last_index[s[i]-'0']; //calculating the new length of the string
             count[s[i]-'0']++;
             last_index[s[i]-'0']=i; //storing the latest index of the character
         }         
     }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

I'm getting the following error for the above code when the string contains spaces.

Testcases:
"ab cabcbb"

"bbbbb"

"pwwkew"

""

"   "

Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x619000000080 overflowed to 0x619000000040 (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], which is a single file that can be compiled. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: testcases:
"ab cabcbb"

"bbbbb"

"pwwkew"

""
"   "

Comment: If you want to extend your question, just [edit] that. Also, while you're at it, make the formatting consistent.

Comment: I added in the body of the question...sorry about putting that in the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
     {
         if(count[s[i]-'0']==0)
         {
```

The value of `' '` (`0x20`) is smaller than the value of `'0'` (`0x30`), so `s[i]- '0'` is a negative value for `s[i]` containing a space char. The conversion of this value to `size_t` (the type used for indices) yields a value pretty close to the maximum, which is out of bounds of the `vector`.

Comment: thanks a lot for this valuable info....so how should i proceed in this case...or should I look for another approach

Comment: @AbhinavAashish I haven't gone through all of your algorithm, but it seems like adding the minimum possible char value should allow you to convert from the rance of possible chars to the range `[0, 255]`. Alternatively you could achieve the same by doing a cast to `unsigned char`. I assume this is what you're after to get indices in the vector? Why are you erasing a whole range of counts btw?

Comment: @AbhinavAashish Also you may be interested in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858154/2991525 I think difference with your approach is the fact that you're trying to use a `vector` not a `unordered_map`